# Using a Unique Id for Backend lookup for cordova/ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

I am building an android phone app that does not have login/authentication screen.
I want to add the functionality to backup/restore some data user entered in the app.
I have a webserver with a webservice written in C#.

My initial plan was to use the deviceId, to identify the device, lookup in the backend table and backup/restore the data, but i realize deviceId is not reliable.

My other options are to

1. Ask for an email at the time of backup,send a verification code to verify and save the email address as the lookup key in the backend,but there is extra work involved. But this will help in case of reinstalls, since i can ask for email verification again.
2. use ng-persist, create a GUID from C# backend(first time) and save using ng-persist.Not sure if ng-persist works after a phone reset or an OS upgrade.

Do i have any simpler options available to make this work ?
Noticed this plugin which says,will generate unique id even after an uninstall.
[UniqueDeviceID](https://alexdisler.com/2015/04/23/persist-data-mobile-device-app-removed-uninstalled-cordova-ionic/)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use **option 1**. Of course it is not necessary to verify the e-mail - just type the e-mail address and store it to your database table.

Your idea with the device's ID or the Unique ID is **not good** because if I change my Android device it will generate different ID and then you can not provide my data to my new device... actually you "lock" this data to a specific device.

Comment: I may go that route, i still think its a good idea to verify email address.